# How do I omit the leading 0 from a 128C bar code?

Tags: delphi, barcode, fastreport

If I put 12345, for example, in a "text" bar code's property, the output is 012345.

This "0" is the problem. How I can remove this?

I'm using Delphi 2010 and FastReport 4.9.72.

Answer (score 11):

A Code 128C barcode needs to be an even number of digits. This is by design.

There is a 1:1 mapping between the numbers and the resulting output, and the output is 2-digit aligned. In the case of `1` the Code 128C representation of this number is `01`

if the value was `12` then the underlying representation would be `12`

so the digits `628` can only be represented by `0628`

The wikipedia article about [Code 128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) explains the differences between the 128A, 128B and 128C encodings.

Comment: +1 - Switch the subset if you need to remove the leading zero.  Subsets A & B don't have the "even number of digits" requirement that C does.

Answer (score 1):

To remove leading zeros from a string:

```
function RemoveLeadingZeros(const S: String): String;
var
  I, NumZeros: Integer;
begin
  Len := 0;
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    if S[I] <> '0' then Break;
    Inc(NumZeros);
  end;
  if NumZeros > 0 then
    Result := Copy(S, NumZeros+1, MaxInt)
  else
    Result := S:
end;
```